# Mongodb delete subdocument

Tags: javascript, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to delete a subdocument in mongoDb but can't succeed in it. I've tried with $update,$push and $pull but I'm not successful.

I have the following document:

```
db.users.findOne({"_id": ObjectId("545677a9e4b0e0ef9379993c")})
{
    "_class" : "com.xxx.xxx.server.da.User",
    "_id" : ObjectId("545677a9e4b0e0ef9379993c"),
    "bookSummaries" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("545677e7e4b0e0ef9379993d"),
            "isbn" : "2746969644"
            "title": "test title"
        },      
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("546a522a44ae4f5e652fdca7"),           
            "loanSummaries" : [
                {
                    "loanStatus" : "REQUESTED",
                    "loanId" : "5473992044aec466a619290c"
                },
                {
                    "loanStatus" : "REQUESTED",
                    "loanId" : "5473997d44aec466a619290d"
                },
                {
                    "loanStatus" : "REQUESTED",
                    "loanId" : "547605a744ae0f0d558ae757"
                }
            ],
            "testArray" : [
                {
                    "title" : "Back to the future",
                    "id" : "test"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Back to the future",
                    "id" : "test2"
                },
                {
                    "title" : "Back to the future",
                    "id" : "test3"
                },
                "test ",
                "test ",
                "test 2",
                "test 2",
                {
                    "loanStatus" : "REQUESTED"
                }
            ],
            "title" : "Back to the future"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I'm trying to create the queries to:

1. delete the whole "testArray" subdocument for only this specific subdocument
2. delete a specific loanSummaries give its loanId for this specific subdocument

Can you help me creating those queries? I've seen several post like this one, but it is not the same problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently had the same problem where I had to remove a nested subarray. In the query you need to identify the exact object that you want to remove, and then in your update query you can use the `$` sign as index for the object in the array that you want to pull.

```
var query = {
       "_id" : ObjectId(someUserId),
       "bookSummaries._id" : ObjectId(bookId), //might also work with isbn as long as it is uniq
       "bookSummaries.loanSummaries.loanId" : loanId
 };

var updateQuery = {
      "$pull" : {
          "bookSummaries.$.loanSummaries" : {
                 "loanId": loadId
          }
      }
}
```

### Update

I tried the following queries in my shell which worked fine. You will have to enter the appropirate ids.

```
var query = { "_id" : ObjectId("53b73b1108fe927c0e00007f"),  "bookSummaries._id" : ObjectId("53b73b1108fe927c0e00007f"), "bookSummaries.loanSummaries.loanId" : "53b73b1108fe927c0e00007f" }

var updateQuery = { "$pull" : { "bookSummaries.$.loanSummaries" : {  "loanId": "53b73b1108fe927c0e00007f"  } } }
```

### Update 2

If you already know the index of item/object you want to remove you can use the queries below in order to achieve this.

Find the document you want to edit

```
var query = {
   "_id" : ObjectId(someUserId),
};
```

Unset the object you want to remove

```
var update1 = {
  "$unset" : {
      "bookSummaries.1.loanSummaries.2" : 1
  }
}
```

Pull the object which has the value null.

```
var update2 = {
  "$pull" : {
      "bookSummaries.1.loanSummaries" : null
  }
}
```

And to remove you can basically use the same queries.

Find the document you want to edit

```
var query = {
   "_id" : ObjectId(someUserId),
};
```

Unset the object you want to remove

```
var update1 = {
  "$unset" : {
      "bookSummaries.0.testArray" : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I use it directly in mongo shell?

Comment: Ok thanks, but the 1st var (query) does not work. Indeed, I can't add the second and 3rd parameter (bookSummaries._id and bookSummaries.loanSummaries.loanId). It seems that the syntax with "." is not supported. I'm getting the error message _SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL_

Comment: What version of mongodb are you running? It worked fine when i tried it. I Update med answer to display my queries.

Comment: I finally made it working, thanks! And do you have any idea for the 1st part of my question?

Comment: You can basically use the same query, you will have to $unset the testArray.

Comment: I finally did it with the following query: `db.users.update(query,{$unset:{"bookSummaries.$.testArray":1}})`. It allowed me to remove the field without knowing its index.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar but delete multiple subdocuments instead of just one. My query included an array of ids and this worked for me:

```
User.updateOne(
      { _id: userId },
      {
        $pull: { bookSummaries: { _id: { $in: ids } } },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Because MongoDB provides a full JavaScript environment you can easily manipulate the document and save the data back to the db.

*Note: if you are using MongoDB with php or python etc. there are equivalent ways to do that.

1.to delete whole "testArray" subdocument for only this specific subdocument for example index(1) do

```
db.users.find({"_id": ObjectId("545677a9e4b0e0ef9379993c")}).forEach(function (user) {
    delete user.bookSummaries[1].testArray;
    //Saveing the changes 
    db.users.save(user);
 });
```

2. to delete a specific loanSummaries give its loanId for this specific subdocument for example  id 5473992044aec466a619290c do

   ```
   db.users.find({"_id": ObjectId("545677a9e4b0e0ef9379993c")}).forEach(function (user) {
       var loanToDelete = "5473992044aec466a619290c";
       var loanIndexToDelete = -1;

       var i;
       for(i in user.bookSummaries[1].loanSummaries) {
           if(user.bookSummaries[1].loanSummaries[i].loanId === loanToDelete) {
               loanIndexToDelete = i;
               break;
           }
       }

       if (loanIndexToDelete > -1) {
         delete user.bookSummaries[1].loanSummaries[loanIndexToDelete];
       }

       //Saving the changes
       db.users.save(users);
   });
   ```

Comment: How can I user your example for 1. but giving a query instead of a specific index of the array? I would like to do something like: delete user.bookSummaries[{"_id":ObjectId("xyz")}].testArray; isn't there another way without iterating accross the whole array?

Comment: To my knowledge MongoDB store document as one piece into the disc. So even if you use some sort of API   Behind the scene you have to retrieve all the array data and iterating through it and search for your id. If you want to find something without iterating accross the whole array you will have to arrange your data in a different way and use indexes